# WebServer or SocketProgramming for android

Tags: android, webserver

I want to write an ecommerce app for android. My question is:
for my server Whether should I use a web server or use socket programming to create my own server? 
I want the server to be accessible only through my client app.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For an eCommerce app, I recommend you to use web service other than socket. You can implement simple authentication mechanism for restricting the access.

And the sun.net.httpserver package is very convenient for you to start with. You might also want to try NanoHttpd.